# Using epoll with NetLink (socket) and Ncurses

Tags: c, linux, sockets, event-handling

I need to write an event loop in my app in order to handle both all the events sent from the user to an ncurses interface and all the messages sent via netlink from a kernel module.

I have two questions.

1. How can I make the socket non-blocking? (`fcntl(sock_fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);` maybe/only?)
2. How can I get the `fd` of the terminal (ncurses) so I can add it to epoll's events?

This is how I start my socket:

```
int net_init(void){
    int sock_fd;
    struct sockaddr_nl src_addr, dest_addr;

    sock_fd = socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, get_netlink_id());  <---- autonegotiation with the kernel module.
    if(sock_fd < 0){
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&src_addr, 0, sizeof(src_addr));
    src_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    src_addr.nl_pid = getpid();

    bind(sock_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&src_addr, sizeof(src_addr));

    memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(dest_addr));
    memset(&dest_addr, 0, sizeof(dest_addr));
    dest_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    dest_addr.nl_pid = 0;
    dest_addr.nl_groups = 0;

    nlh = (struct nlmsghdr *)new(NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD));
    memset(nlh, 0, NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD));
    nlh->nlmsg_len = NLMSG_SPACE(MAX_PAYLOAD);
    nlh->nlmsg_pid = getpid();
    nlh->nlmsg_flags = 0;

    strcpy(NLMSG_DATA(nlh), ""); <--- Send empty string to the kernel module so it knows to what PID it should send data

    iov.iov_base = (void *)nlh;
    iov.iov_len = nlh->nlmsg_len;
    msg.msg_name = (void *)&dest_addr;
    msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(dest_addr);
    msg.msg_iov = &iov;
    msg.msg_iovlen = 1;

    sendmsg(sock_fd, &msg, 0);

    return sock_fd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On (1) you typically use `fcntl` with F_GETFL and use the returned flags for the subsequent F_SETFL call.

```
 fcntl(sock_fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
```

(2) I've never seen a fool proof answer to this.  There is nothing in the curses api that I know of that will reveal its file descriptor nor allow you to designate another one which leads me to think it is always stdout.  I did a `strace` on some simple programs and curses blindly did its thing stdin, out & err regardless.  So I don't see that you have any choice but to assume stdout is what you must poll on, possibly after checking that stdout is attached to a terminal (`isatty`) and/or that it hasn't been redirected, most problematically I would assume, to stderr.

If someone has greater insight I would like to hear it.

As an aside, I wonder if you have considered putting the curses stuff into a separate thread and just communicating between threads as appropriate.  The reasoning being that if it isn't a dead simple curses interface it is *really* easy to tie yourself into knots trying to keep track of where you are in curses while managing other things.

Comment: What about if my app is running via SSH? Will stdin be valid?

Comment: I assume.  From what I have read the headaches there tend to be terminal incapability and the like.  It's a good point tho.  It makes using isatty and the like above pointless.  Really the more I think about it I don't see how stdin isn't the proper assumption.